# How to send NTLM authentication in soap header?

Tags: soap, ntlm

I could invoke service in soap ui with my credentials or calling same service with node soap package , but I need to invoke It by sending request with soap header, but I couldn't find any examples about that, so is It even possible?

Comment: Good question. NTLM authenticates a connection, not a single request. If you want to put the credentials inside the SOAP header (instead of the HTTP Authenticate request header), this means that each SOAP request will include the credentials independently of the connection reuse (HTTP Keep-Alive). This is contradictory with NTLM over HTTP design, for this reason I _believe_ this is not possible (if I had a proof I would post an answer instead of a comment).